# Oracle vs MS SQL UPDATE using IN SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-update

This SQL works fine on MS SQL Server but produces an error "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis".

SQL:

```
UPDATE DELIVERY
SET VISIBLE = 0
WHERE DELIVERY.ID
IN 
(
    SELECT DELIVERY.ID FROM delivery WHERE DELIVERY.VISIBLE = 1
    EXCEPT
        SELECT DELIVERY.ID FROM delivery LEFT JOIN inventory ON INVENTORY.DELIVERYID = DELIVERY.ID
            WHERE ((DELIVERY.VISIBLE = 1) AND (INVENTORY.VISIBLE = 1)) AND (INVENTORY.INVENTORYSTATE = 3)
);
```

Is there a way to get this to work on Oracle or is an UPDATE using an IN with SELECT statements just conceptually wrong?

Comment: use Where Exists in Oracle

Comment: @Piyush Thanks I will have a look at that now...

Comment: IN can also work in Oracle

Comment: OK Look, Change EXCEPT to MINUS in Oracle

Comment: @Piyush Thanks, the way i've got my SQL setup to use both MS SQL and ORACLE the MINUS option seems to be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle, IN Can also work, just change the EXCEPT to MINUS in Oracle
http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/update.php

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10007.htm

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.0-en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

An Sample Example for this will be

```
UPDATE DELIVERY
SET VISIBLE = 0
WHERE DELIVERY.ID
IN 
(
    (SELECT DELIVERY.ID FROM delivery WHERE DELIVERY.VISIBLE = 1)
    MINUS
    (SELECT DELIVERY.ID 
    FROM delivery LEFT JOIN inventory ON INVENTORY.DELIVERYID = DELIVERY.ID
    WHERE (((DELIVERY.VISIBLE = 1) AND (INVENTORY.VISIBLE = 1)) 
          AND (INVENTORY.INVENTORYSTATE = 3)))
);
```

Comment: I think an `INNER JOIN` would work in the subquery too since `NULL`s will be excluded in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @David Faber:- OP already has the same query in MSSQL, just want thats not working in Oracle

Comment: Yes - I am simply noting that the `LEFT JOIN` doesn't do anything here - no `NULL`s will be returned due to the `WHERE`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can modify this query so that it works in both SQL Server **and** Oracle:

```
UPDATE delivery d
   SET d.visible = 0
 WHERE d.visible = 1
   AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM inventory i
                     WHERE i.deliveryid = d.id
                       AND i.visible = 1
                       AND i.inventorystate = 3 )
```

This will update `DELIVERY` setting `visible` = 0 wherever `visible` = 1 but there is no corresponding record in `INVENTORY` with `visible` = 1 and `inventorystate` = 3.